# Macro annotation with default arguments

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

[Getting Parameters from Scala Macro Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631372/getting-parameters-from-scala-macro-annotation) explains how to get parameters from a macro annotation. However, if I have several parameters with default values:

```
class Foo(b: Boolean = false, i: Int = 0) extends StaticAnnotation { ... }
```

I need to write (based on the answer to that question)

```
val (b, i) = c.prefix.tree match {
  case q"new Foo(..$args)" => ???
}
```

The logic in `???` seems to become very nasty: I need to handle both positional and named parameters, no simple access to the default values, etc. Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: So far there's no better way unfortunately.

Comment: If you need to get the values of the parameters, this works:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42961043/3669757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a limited solution, but

```
// same constructor parameters and defaults as Foo
class FooArgs(b: Boolean = false, i: Int = 0)

val args = c.prefix.tree match {
  case q"new Foo(...$args)" => c.eval(c.Expr[FooArgs](q"new some_package.FooArgs(...$args)"))
}
```