# Pass type identifier to static macro annotation

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Is there a way to pass a type identifier to a macro annotation? Here is what I mean:

```
@compileTimeOnly("Compile-time only annotation")
class mymacro(val typeName: universe.TypeName) extends StaticAnnotation { // <-- does not work
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro impl
}

object mymacro {
  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*) = //...
}
```

use-case:

```
trait SomeTrait

@mymacro(SomeTrait)
class Test {
    //...
}
```

Or maybe there is any other way to pass Type identifier of an arbitrary non-generic type to a macro annotation implementation?

**Motivation behind this:** I need to generate some `class Test` member function `def foo` depending on the type passed as an argument to the macro annotation (`SomeTrait`).

Comment: What is `universe` in `universe.TypeName`?

Comment: If you want you can use `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeName` instead of string but then you'll have to cast. `scala.reflect.runtime.universe` and `c.universe` (for different `c`) are different.

Comment: You could try passing the companion object (I think `@specialized` does this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can pass `typeName` as a string

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("Compile-time only annotation")
class mymacro(typeName: String) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro mymacro.impl
}

object mymacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val typeName = TypeName(c.prefix.tree match {
      case q"new mymacro(${str: String})" => str
    })

    println(typeName)

    q"..$annottees"
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
trait SomeTrait

@mymacro("SomeTrait")
class Test 

// scalac: SomeTrait
```

[Getting Parameters from Scala Macro Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631372/getting-parameters-from-scala-macro-annotation)

If you prefer the companion-object approach proposed by **@user** in comments then you can do

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("Compile-time only annotation")
class mymacro(companionObject: Any) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro mymacro.impl
}

object mymacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val companionTrait = c.typecheck(c.prefix.tree) match {
      case q"new mymacro($arg)" => arg.symbol.companion
    }

    println(companionTrait)

    q"..$annottees"
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
trait SomeTrait
object SomeTrait

@mymacro(SomeTrait)
class Test

//scalac: trait SomeTrait
```